# Subscription capability

Tags: bigcommerce

We have a series of products that are subscription based. ie: first 7 days free, then a monthly or annual fee with a start date and finish date. Is this possible ? and could we drive this through the REST API ?

Comment: It's likely possible, but you've included so few details about the current products (their technologies, for instance) that it's hard to give an answer beyond "it depends".  Could you update your question?

Comment: @marc did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment to answer -

I would like to second @KimballRobinson's comments. It might be possible. The REST API by itself gives you access to store data. You can create products and maintain them. In your case, things to consider - what is the product taxonomy like and can it be defined as custom fields or something of that sort. Maybe you can set it up in a way such that you charge/invoice the customer for the same product every month or annually. There are ways in which you can implement subscription. If you define details more on the scope of what you are trying to accomplish, it will be easier to figure out

Comment: How do we capture the vendor specific cc data to either create subscriptions as part of bigcommerce checkout or do recurring charges  outside of bigcommerce?  Has anyone done this?